# Web api mvc incoming XML root differs

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

I need to develop a web api MVC REST service to consume XML from a third party.

The project has been created using CodeFirst Entity Framework based on a sample XML file.

I received test XML files for the update, post and delete, to my surprise the root xml element differs per method.

The POST root is CreateSomething

The PUT root is UpdateSometing

In the model I created the root is always CreateSomething, for all methods.

Do I need to create extra models for the different method? Or is there another way to get around this?

Hope I made my problem clear.

Thanks in advance

Regards

EDIT:
This is the expected XML input, this works for the POST.

```
<CreateBookingRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ID>a10601e4-c24d-4e7d-9c11-ae5a35fb5770</ID>
  <ApiKey>sample string 2</ApiKey>
  <Booking>
<BookingId>22c9a3ce-58d1-4a7e-b483-897e29aa3f6a</BookingId>
<Travellers>      
  <Traveller Id="8">
    <TravellerId>0792a822-92d0-4e9a-88b2-f6fae02221f2</TravellerId>
    <DateOfBirth>2016-04-13T11:56:02.4407937+02:00</DateOfBirth>
    <Gender>sample string 3</Gender>
    <FirstName>sample string 4</FirstName>
    <LastName>sample string 5</LastName>
    <CountryCode>sample string 6</CountryCode>
    <PrefferedLanguageCode>sample string 7</PrefferedLanguageCode>
    <Communication>
      <CommunicationId>fbf1eeda-73bf-4381-a751-5a2da346e7a0</CommunicationId>
      <Email>
        <EmailId>45069245-c2af-4c55-934f-e033da0fbb5e</EmailId>
        <Value>sample string 2</Value>
        <Culture>sample string 3</Culture>
      </Email>
      <Sms>
        <SmsId>261db3a9-d858-47e9-934b-07981d203155</SmsId>
        <Value>sample string 2</Value>
        <Culture>sample string 3</Culture>
      </Sms>
      <EmailId>6a4005d4-8f05-4999-9098-1078b2c12ebf</EmailId>
      <SmsId>d5d8f3df-b08c-4954-9e6c-b29a3a74a3e8</SmsId>
    </Communication>
    <BookingId>4baf0cad-75d8-4067-a3d1-bd70f1b219ad</BookingId>
  </Traveller>
</Travellers>    
  </Booking>
</CreateBookingRequest>
```

But the PUT XML input looks like this.

```
<UpdateBookingRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ID>a10601e4-c24d-4e7d-9c11-ae5a35fb5770</ID>
  <ApiKey>sample string 2</ApiKey>
  <Booking>
    <BookingId>22c9a3ce-58d1-4a7e-b483-897e29aa3f6a</BookingId>
    <Travellers>      
  <Traveller Id="8">
    <TravellerId>0792a822-92d0-4e9a-88b2-f6fae02221f2</TravellerId>
    <DateOfBirth>2016-04-13T11:56:02.4407937+02:00</DateOfBirth>
    <Gender>sample string 3</Gender>
    <FirstName>sample string 4</FirstName>
    <LastName>sample string 5</LastName>
    <CountryCode>sample string 6</CountryCode>
    <PrefferedLanguageCode>sample string 7</PrefferedLanguageCode>
    <Communication>
      <CommunicationId>fbf1eeda-73bf-4381-a751-5a2da346e7a0</CommunicationId>
      <Email>
        <EmailId>45069245-c2af-4c55-934f-e033da0fbb5e</EmailId>
        <Value>sample string 2</Value>
        <Culture>sample string 3</Culture>
      </Email>
      <Sms>
        <SmsId>261db3a9-d858-47e9-934b-07981d203155</SmsId>
        <Value>sample string 2</Value>
        <Culture>sample string 3</Culture>
      </Sms>
      <EmailId>6a4005d4-8f05-4999-9098-1078b2c12ebf</EmailId>
      <SmsId>d5d8f3df-b08c-4954-9e6c-b29a3a74a3e8</SmsId>
    </Communication>
    <BookingId>4baf0cad-75d8-4067-a3d1-bd70f1b219ad</BookingId>
  </Traveller>
</Travellers>    
  </Booking>
</UpdateBookingRequest>
```

The serialization of the XML will fail because of the changed root xml.

I could just add another model like UpdateBookingRequest?

Sample code:

```
// PUT: api/CreateBookingRequests/5    
[Route("update/{id:guid}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult PutCreateBookingRequest(Guid id, CreateBookingRequest createBookingRequest)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (id != createBookingRequest.ID)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    db.Entry(createBookingRequest).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!CreateBookingRequestExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code to get a better understanding of what you've done and also to allow others to try and recreate your issue and provide a solution

Comment: Hi, added more info. Thanks

Comment: Show sample code for the methods that handle the xml. It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: Hi added the sample code for the PUT method

Comment: Ok i think I'm getting a clearer idea of what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you are asking completely.

Here is a class that will act as the base for your models

```
public abstract class RequestModelBase {
    //All the properties that are common to your models
}
```

Then create classes for your different models that inherit from the common base

```
public class UpdateBookingRequest : RequestModelBase {...}

public class CreateBookingRequest : RequestModelBase {...}
```

**UPDATE** based on your comments here is an example controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/bookings")]
public class BookingsController: ApiController {

    // POST: api/Bookings  
    [HttpPost]      
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostBooking(CreateBookingRequest request) {...}

    // PUT: api/Bookings/a10601e4-c24d-4e7d-9c11-ae5a35fb5770  
    [HttpPut]      
    [Route("{id:guid}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutBooking(Guid id, UpdateBookingRequest request) {...}

    // DELETE: api/Bookings/a10601e4-c24d-4e7d-9c11-ae5a35fb5770  
    [HttpDelete]      
    [Route("{id:guid}")]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteBooking(Guid id) {...}
}
```

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for! Going to try it and let yopu know if it is working. Thanks

Comment: Do I also need to add another controller besides the already existing CreateBookingRequestController?

Comment: No you should be able to put all your actions into one controller. Like `BookingsController` with actions like `CreatBooking` and `UpdateBooking`. Noticed in your sample code that you are missing `[HttpPutAttribute]` on the PUT action

Comment: Thanks! Will build this tommorrow

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, feel free to up vote. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Nkosi, I run into another issue. I use this dbset in the dbContext:     'code'public DbSet<CreateBookingRequest> CreateBookingRequest { get; set; }. When I execute the PUT with the UpdateBookingRequest, I receive the error: The entity type UpdateBookingRequest is not part of the model for the current context

Comment: @Heisa: Which would be correct. Ok, You seem to be mixing different concepts with your data models. you will need to generalize you dbContext to handle the different models which technically are all the same. Change `DbSet<CreateBookingRequest> CreateBookingRequest` to `DbSet<BookingRequest> BookingRequests` the base class of your models.